# Count,Distinct and No repetition in R

Tags: r, count, distinct

I have the following data set

```
zz <- "Date Token
20170120    12073300000000000000
20170120    18732300000000000000
20170120    15562500000000000000
20170120    13959500000000000000
20170120    13959500000000000000
20170121    13932200000000000000
20170121    10589400000000000000
20170121    15562500000000000000
20170121    13959500000000000000
20170121    13959500000000000000
20170121    10589400000000000000"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

I am trying to get to below stats

```
Date       # of Transactions    Unique Token    New Token
20170120    5                    4                4
20170121    6                    4                3 

# of Transactions - Total Transactions (includes duplicate tokens)
unique Token - No duplicates
New Token - No repetition with other dates.
```

**Edit1:**
New Token - On the first day - all unique token are new tokens. from the next day - need to compare each day unique card and see if it is repeated from the prev. day, if not repeated then its a new token for that day
**Edit2:**
Essentially i have 1 month range of data and i am trying to find for those 30 days - on each day what is the new Token . has there been an improvement in new token on daily basis.

Comment: I don't get your `New Token`. Shouldn't it be 3 for `...120` date and 4 for `...121` date?

Comment: @Sotos for first day - 4 unique token( one duplicate) and all of them are new tokens . For next day 3 new token as 15562500000000000000,13959500000000000000,13959500000000000000 have been repeated  from prev. day

Comment: ahh...ok got it.

Comment: why the unique token for day 2 change from 4 to 5 in your editing?

Comment: @mt1022 there is no edit there. unique token - no duplicates. The issue is more on the new token. The edit was for explaning new token

Comment: For second day, there are 6 token in total. both `105894` and `139595` are duplicated, so there are 4 unique token, right?

Comment: Unique token is for that particular day - on 21st 139322,105894,155625,139595 are unique tokens for that day

Comment: @RUser in your comment 139595 appears twice, so there are only 4 unique tokens in this day

Comment: My bad. Corrected the post

Comment: @mt1022 you were right, pls. post . will mark as answer

Comment: You can see it now.

Comment: I don't get the new token : do you want the unique tokens (as 4 on the first date suggest) or the number of new tokens (including repetitions), as 3 on the second date suggests. Because you only have 2 new unique tokens on the second date (139322 105894), the latter being repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give what you want:

```
Data %>%
    mutate(new.tk = !duplicated(Token)) %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarize(
        count = n(),
        unique = n_distinct(Token),
        new = ifelse(Date[1] == Data$Date[1],  sum(new.tk), sum(Token %in% Token[new.tk]))
)

# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#       Date count unique   new
#      <int> <int>  <int> <int>
# 1 20170120     5      4     4
# 2 20170121     6      4     3
```

Comment: For new token - is there a way to check  not only for the prev day , but for entire month

Comment: @RUser I think the can be done by grouping by month. But it seems more complex operation than first thought.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `purrr`. Note that I don't get the results you gave in your question, as you only have 2 unique new tokens for the second date

```
df <- Data %>% 
    group_by(Date) %>% 
    summarise(N_transac = n(), 
              unique_token = n_distinct(Token),
              tokens = list(Token)) %>%
    mutate(prev = lag(tokens, 1), 
           new = purrr::map2_int(tokens, prev, ~length(setdiff(.x, .y)))) %>%
    select(-tokens, -prev)
df
# A tibble: 2 <U+00D7> 4
      Date N_transac unique_token   new
     <int>     <int>        <int> <int>
1 20170120         5            4     4
2 20170121         6            4     2
```